# Binary Search in large .txt with python (ordered by hash)

Tags: python, algorithm, search, text-files, binary-search

I would like to search a very large text file in which `SHA1` Hashes are sorted by hash values using Python. The text file has `10GB` and `500 000 000` lines. Each line looks like this:

```
000009F0DA8DA60DFCC93B39F3DD51A088ED3FD9:27
```

I compare thereby whether a given hash value occurs in the file. I tried it with **BinarySearch**, but it only works with a small test file. If I use the file with `10GB` the search takes much too long and the process is killed sometime because `16GB RAM` was exceeded.

```py
f=open('testfile.txt', 'r')
text=f.readlines()
data=text
#print data
x = '000009F0DA8DA60DFCC93B39F3DD51A088ED3FD9:27'
def binarySearch(data, l, r, x):

  while l <= r:
    mid = l + (r - l)/2;
    # Check if x is present at mid
    if data[mid] == x:
        return mid
    # If x is greater, ignore left half
    elif data[mid] < x:
        l = mid + 1
        #print l
    # If x is smaller, ignore right half
    else:
        r = mid - 1
        #print r
# If we reach here, then the element
# was not present
  return -1


result = binarySearch(data,0, len(data)-1, x)
if result != -1:
   print "Element is present at index % d" % result
else:
   print "Element is not present in array"
```

Is there a way to load the `10GB` text file once into RAM and access it over and over again? I have `16GB RAM` available. That should be enough, right? 
Is there anything else I could do to speed up the search? Unfortunately I don't know any more.

Comment: There is an implementation of `binarySearch` in the Python Standard Library, search bisect.

Comment: As a tip, you _don't_ have to load it all at once; can load 50%, process it (store search algorithm information), then load other 50%, repeat, and apply algorithm (can also be done part-wise). But unless background programs eat up the 6GB (check w/ TaskManager), you can freely fit all 10GB in memory

Comment: If you want to go 1000 times faster, use C language.

Comment: if you're still going to load it into memory, you better use a hashmap for O(1) search

Comment: `If I use the file with 10GB the search takes much too long and the process is killed sometime because 16GB RAM was exceeded.` - these are two unrelated problems

Comment: The first part ( before colon ) is clearly 20 byte sha1 hash, but what is `:27` in your sample?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon can you make an little example?

Comment: @tuxdna the :27 is a count variable but not important for me

Comment: @mangusta My main Problem is, the Search takes to long to finish

Comment: okay, can you share some more example entries from you input file ?

Comment: does anyone still have an idea for an example of how I can load the textfile completely into RAM to be able to access it at any time? I would like to read the file into the RAM when starting the server so that it is always available.

Comment: @tuxdna 000000005AD76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4:4
00000000A8DAE4228F821FB418F59826079BF368:3
00000000DD7F2A1C68A35673713783CA390C9E93:630
00000001E225B908BAC31C56DB04D892E47536E0:5
00000006BAB7FC3113AA73DE3589630FC08218E7:2
00000008CD1806EB7B9B46A8F87690B2AC16F617:4
0000000A0E3B9F25FF41DE4B5AC238C2D545C7A8:15
0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38:16
0000000CAEF405439D57847A8657218C618160B2:15
0000000FC1C08E6454BED24F463EA2129E254D43:40

Comment: @FelixGrötz I'm unfamiliar with your specific task, but the idea is to _strip_ irrelevant information and _condense_ leftovers via conversion that doesn't lose any relevant information. For example, if the goal was to find the longest line among a million lines, you'd convert that file into another file whose lines store _lengths_ of the original. The size would be reduced by the average line length - e.g. x100.

Comment: @FelixGrötz Alternatively, does this accurately describe the task? "Find occurrence of a string in a large text file" (Then what's "occurrence" - index, frequency?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your sample input as `input.txt` as below

```
000000005AD76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4:4
00000000A8DAE4228F821FB418F59826079BF368:3
00000000DD7F2A1C68A35673713783CA390C9E93:630
00000001E225B908BAC31C56DB04D892E47536E0:5
00000006BAB7FC3113AA73DE3589630FC08218E7:2
00000008CD1806EB7B9B46A8F87690B2AC16F617:4
0000000A0E3B9F25FF41DE4B5AC238C2D545C7A8:15
0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38:16
0000000CAEF405439D57847A8657218C618160B2:15
0000000FC1C08E6454BED24F463EA2129E254D43:40
```

And remove the counts so your file becomes (`in.txt` below ):

```
000000005AD76BD555C1D6D771DE417A4B87E4B4
00000000A8DAE4228F821FB418F59826079BF368
00000000DD7F2A1C68A35673713783CA390C9E93
00000001E225B908BAC31C56DB04D892E47536E0
00000006BAB7FC3113AA73DE3589630FC08218E7
00000008CD1806EB7B9B46A8F87690B2AC16F617
0000000A0E3B9F25FF41DE4B5AC238C2D545C7A8
0000000A1D4B746FAA3FD526FF6D5BC8052FDB38
0000000CAEF405439D57847A8657218C618160B2
0000000FC1C08E6454BED24F463EA2129E254D43
```

This will ensure you have fixed size for each entry.

Now you can use mmap based file reading approach as in here https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

```
import mmap
import os

FIELD_SIZE=40+1  # also include newline separator

def binarySearch(mm, l, r, x):
    while l <= r:
        mid = int(l + (r - l)/2);
        # Check if x is present at mid
        mid_slice = mm[mid*FIELD_SIZE:(mid+1)*FIELD_SIZE]
        mid_slice = mid_slice.decode('utf-8').strip()
        # print(mid_slice)
        if mid_slice == x:
            return mid
        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        elif mid_slice < x:
            l = mid + 1
            #print l
        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else:
            r = mid - 1
            #print r

    # If we reach here, then the element
    # was not present
    return -1

# text=f.readlines()
# data=text
#print data
x = '0000000CAEF405439D57847A8657218C618160B2'

with open('in.txt', 'r+b') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    result = binarySearch(mm, 0, size/FIELD_SIZE, x)
    if result != -1:
        print("Element is present at index % d" % result)
    else:
        print("Element is not present in array")
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ python3 find.py 
Element is present at index  8
```

Since the file is not read completely in memory, there won't be out of memory errors.

Comment: thank you very much! It works with a very good performance. I want to get it to run via CGI now. Unfortunately this does not work. Do you still have an idea what it could be?

Comment: to be more concrete: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied is the Error. The Cgi Script has the correct rights (chmod 775). it looks like no access to the text file is possible

Comment: EDIT: if i call it in the cgi directory with python file.py, i normally get the desired result. But if I call the whole thing via CGI, I get the permission error

Comment: your file must be accessible by the user running web-server

Comment: your right..Has to ask the administrator for that. let you know on monday if it worked :)

Comment: you could also convert this script into a network service, and let your CGI script connect to the service over TCP / HTTP.

Comment: How can I do that? A little example would be great.

Comment: it works great :). I would like to display the result of a CGI script in the original HTML page. The best way is to trigger the CGI process with a click on a button but not reload the page. I read this about AJAX but how can I integrate the result of the CGI script into the HTML page? Do you have any Idea?

Comment: You may want to to start a new question for this problem, and describe what you want to achieve there.

Comment: I tried it but not so much response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164870/how-do-i-get-it-to-display-the-result-on-the-original-html-page-after-executing