# How do I get it to display the result on the original HTML page after executing a CGI script?

Tags: python, html, ajax, cgi, response.redirect

I would like to display the result of a CGI script on the original HTML page. The best way is to trigger the CGI process with a click on a button but not reload the page.

I read this about Ajax, but how can I integrate the result of the CGI script into the HTML page?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi, cgitb
import time
import os
import mmap

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
password = form.getvalue('passwordcheck')
inputformular = form.getvalue('myfield')
x=inputformular
print ("""Content-Type:text/html\n
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Passwordcheck</title>
</head>
<body>
""")
start = time.time()
##################################

FIELD_SIZE=40+1  # Also include a newline separator
def binarySearch(mm, l, r, x):
    while l <= r:
        mid = int(l + (r - l)/2);
        # Check if x is present at mid
        mid_slice = mm[mid*FIELD_SIZE:(mid+1)*FIELD_SIZE]
        mid_slice = mid_slice.decode('utf-8').strip()
        #print(mid_slice)
        if mid_slice == x:
            return mid
        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        elif mid_slice < x:
            l = mid + 1
            #print l
        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else:
            r = mid - 1
            #print r

    # If we reach here, then the element
    # was not present
    return -1

# text=f.readlines()
# data=text
#print data
#x = 'C78A6A8BFA18BABB7762CEF6AEFA14EE299F10AF'
#x = '0000000CAEF405439D57847A8657218C618160B2'

with open('../stripedpwned.txt', 'r+b') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    result = binarySearch(mm, 0, size/FIELD_SIZE, x)
    if result != -1:
        print("Element is present at index % d" % result)
    else:
        print("Element is not present in array")


###################################
print("<br />")
print("Uebermittelte Daten:<br />")
print("Password:")
print(password)
print("<br />")
print("Der Hash davon:")
print(x)
print("<br />")

end = time.time()
print(end - start)

print("""
</body>
</html>
""")
```

I would like to read the variable "result" in the HTML page without getting directed to the CGI script.

EDIT:

I have the following JavaScript code in my HTML File:

```
function loadCGI(){
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', '../cgi-bin/einlesen.py', false);
httpRequest.send(null);
document.write(httpRequest.responseText);
}
```

So I could read a variable, which I output via the CGI script. E.g. Value=true or something like that.
But how do I manage that first the FormInput of my HTML page is transferred into the CGI script and then I get the result? I could then read this somehow as a JavaScript variable.

Comment: You have two possibilities: JavaScript or an `iframe`. Updating part of a page dynamically with just HTML is not possible.

Comment: @herrbischoff JavaScript would be ok but I don't know how. when I press the button with the POST request, the result should simply be inserted into the HTML page without being redirected to the CGI page

Comment: Think. State your problem clearly. Research.

Comment: @herrbischoff edited the description above

Comment: you would have to assign javascript function to form button (`"onclick="`) and this script should use AJAX to send form data to server and get result. It should also inform browser that it shouldn't reload page. As I remeber it should use `return false`. Or `e.preventDefault()` if you use jQuery.